# Using dlopen and dlsym with a third party c++ library

Tags: c++, shared-libraries, dlopen, dynamic-loading, dlsym

Newbie question. Suppose there is a third party library *ClassLibrary.so*, which contains the class definition of a *ClassTest* and I don't have access to the source of *ClassLibrary.so*. Can I use ClassTest in my code with dlopen and dlsym? Personally, I would like to compile with *ClassLibrary.so* but the client wants to use dlopen and dlsym.

I have not tried much as I don't know how to start. I went through this article https://www.linuxjournal.com/article/3687 but it seems that this article requires access to the source of library to create a function that returns a pointer to the class within the source and use this function with dlopen and dlsym.

Comment: Have you got a header-file such as `ClassLibrary.h`?

Comment: yes. I have the header file.

Comment: You can create a wrapper (another shared object), which is linked against ClassLibrary.so and contains wrapper-functions (actual functions, not methods) for every non-virtual methods of ClassTest (constructors included). The source of ClassLibrary.so is not needed, just the header-file defining ClassTest. Also every components has to be compiled with the same version of the same C++-compiler, using the same compiler-options (nothing new there, that's how C++ is).

Answer (score 1):

> Can I use ClassTest in my code with dlopen and dlsym?

*Maybe*.

If the `ClassLibrary.so` exports all the methods of `ClassTest` *and* `ClassLibrary.h` provides a declaration for `ClassTest` *and* that declaration actually matches that one used when `ClassLibrary.so` was built, *and* you know exact compiler version and flags used to build `ClassLibrary.so`.

In *practice* you probably can't know the compiler version (even if `strings -a ClassLibrary.so` says something like `GCC 10.0.1`, that's not necessarily sufficient), nor the build flags, and you can't know whether developers of `ClassLibrary.so` have played any tricks with the declaration of `ClassTest` (if they even provided such declaration).